# unable to get correct ConnectionString from app.config

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

Let's say we have 2 folder >
1>Original 2> copied. Now
I have copied a full visual project from folder1 to folder2 and changed my connectionstring path with respect to folder2.

```
Folder 1 it was >    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
          <add name="mydata" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\folder1\mydata.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
        </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Connection manager is

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydata"].ConnectionString;
```

,

```
 After coping to folder 2 chanaged path as >

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
            <configuration>
                <connectionStrings>
                  <add name="mydata" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\folder2\mydata.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
                </connectionStrings>
            </configuration>
```

Now, When I try to access the database it always refers to "folder1" database not current "folder2" database.

```
Note:
```

In "folder1" I have published my app and after I copied it to "folder2", so can any one please point out this issue?

Comment: How do you know that is always 'refers' to database in 'folder1'?

Comment: well, if I create any new table or column in folder2 database it through an error "Invalid column name 'new_col_name'". Not only this I checked in Load Event as  MessageBox.Show("Check it" + connectionString); It shows me a folder1 path.

Answer (score 0):

If connectionString shows folder1 in the path, than that's your problem: it hasn't been properly updated. Make sure you saved the file, and search the entire solution for occurences of "folder1".

If this doesn't work (although it should), place breakpoints where the connection the DB is made, and where connectionString is assigned a value, and check the path at every breakpoint to see whether it contains folder1 or folder2.

Comment: To refer connectionstring, I add only "string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydata"].ConnectionString;" this to my files and Not the path.

Comment: you also set ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydata"].ConnectionString at one point or another. check that point.